# OpenRasta project keeps throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: http, rest, openrasta, invalidoperationexception

This happens when the project is running... when we are on a page (for example /Project) everything renders fine... but at random time (I can't figure out when it happens) it just gets thrown.

This is the stacktrace

```
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ThrowIfEventBindingDisallowed() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RemoveSyncEventHookup(Object key, Delegate handler,
RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostNotification)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.remove_PostResolveRequestCache(EventHandler value)
at OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.OpenRastaModule.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Init>b__1() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\446ececd36f5f871\src\OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet\OpenRastaModule.cs:line 75
at OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.OpenRastaModule.Dispose() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\446ececd36f5f871\src\OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet\OpenRastaModule.cs:line 66
at System.Web.HttpApplication.DisposeInternal()
```

I hope someone can clarify what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be because you're on master and that's including some silly code that tries to cleanup stuff that shouldn't be.

Expect a commit this afternoon that'll fix that.

Comment: Well, thank you for the quick reply! Good job on the framework btw!